# Clear Cache in iOS: Deleting Application Data of Other Apps

Tags: ios, iphone, caching

Recently, I have came across many apps which "Clear Cache" on iPhone. They also specify that you may lose some saved data and temp files.

What I know is that Apple doesn't allows you to access data of other Apps neither directory. So, how they are cleaning cache data? Can anyone put some light on it?

Reference: [Magic Phone Cleaner](https://itunes.apple.com/ph/app/magic-phone-cleaner/id1176756975?mt=8)

[Power Clean](https://itunes.apple.com/ph/app/power-clean-delete-duplicate-photos-scan-network/id1115097063?mt=8)

Comment: are you sure they are actually clearing cache?

Comment: I don't know, I want to figure that out. Also, I have literally seen that Storage is decreasing as said. You can try out these apps as our own and see the result.

Comment: You can get a similar effect of forcing a cache clear at time of writing by attempting to rent a movie off iTunes that won't fit on your phone's free space. You will get an error message that the phone doesn't have enough free space and then the cache clear will be triggered on the device and often you will end up with a GB of free space after that.

Answer (score 13):

They simply fill the free space on iPhone temporarily with random data leaving the system with no free space at all.

This forces iOS to clear all temp data, caches and iCloud Photos -if you enabled storage optimization- to clear space. So basically they are tricking the system to force it to clear temp and cached data.

Comment: I already said, "I am not looking for reference". Can you show me how? Do you have an example? Then, please share.

Comment: P.S. - What you have said is already been answered on SO. Can I know how they are tricking?

Answer (score 1):

No app can access anything outside of it's sandbox environment. In other words, technically it's impossible to clean cache on an iPhone unless it's jailbroken. Most of these apps doesn't do what they say, they just give an illusion to user. Loading up the memory can force iOS to terminate other apps in the background but, I it's unlikely that it will give any performance boost.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't clear data in external apps, it clears external data left by apps. Clearing the cache basically deletes all the temporary files.